# Add 3 new numbers before the already formed number

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to add the number `188` before the already formed number, for example, there is the number `110 0000 000`. And according to the assignment, I need it to be `188 110 0000 000`. The most numeric value is `varchar`, and I thought that it could cost like this.

```
update myTable1 myTbl
  set myTbl.NMBCODE='188'+myTbl.NMBCODE --- insert number characters before the main string variable (both varchar values), concatenation..
```

But this method is not correct, since the error `ORA01722-Invalid Number` crashes on `+myTbl.TNMBCODE`
Please tell me what mechanisms exist to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a new string prefix to an existing string; neither of them are really numbers. So you need to use the string concatenation operator `||`, not the arithmetic operator `+`:

```
update myTable1 myTbl
  set myTbl.NMBCODE = '188 ' || myTbl.NMBCODE
```

I've included a space in the string being prepended, otherwise you would end up with `'188110 0000 000'` instead of `'188 110 0000 000'`.

When you use `+` Oracle tries to convert both strings to numbers to add them together, which isn't what you want - if it worked at all you'd get `1100000118` - and while it can happily implicitly convert `'188'` to a number, it fails trying to convert `'110 0000 000'` because of the spaces.